# Ported HTML5 App runs slower than in Phone Browser

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I noticed something I can´t explain. I installed XAMPP on my computer. I copied the code of my HTML5 app inside of the htdocs folder. When i run the Browser on my WP8 (Nokia Lumia 920) and type in the IP of my Computer the App runs at solid 60 FPS. Everything is smooth and fine. 
I tryied to install the App on my Phone using the "Windows Phone-HTML5-App" template given from Visual Studio 2013. Now the application runs on my phone but at 40-50 FPS and is very choppy.
To my mind the App runs in the same Browser. Why there is such a big difference in performance?

Thank You!

Edit:
I changed the MainPage.xaml file. The app was soposed to run in landscape  mode. Now I tried the portraid mode. And everything runs fine at solid 59 FPS. I think the only one who can explain this is the one who wrode the browser! I changed the X and Y axis inside of my camera class.

Answer (score 0):

In general, keep in mind that a phone browser is able to use more resources than an app(doesn't matter if it's Hybrid or not). Usually native apps use those resources more efficient, that's the reason of the lack of fps problems.
Why does this happend? Because every OS is made to in general terms "don't allow an app to block the entire phone".

Comment: The web browser embedded in the application is native. As this is specifically about Windows Phone 8, if you had specific evidence to provide, this would be a better answer. A game on Windows Phone can operate at 60FPS written in C#.